# Writing a set as a union or intersection of a collection of intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let S = 
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \forall y\in \left[0,1\right],\ |y-x| < 2 \}$$

Write the set A as a union or intersection of a collection of intervals.

---

I have trouble interpreting the statement. But this is what I understand:

For every real number x such that for all y between 0 and 1, |y-x| < 2
and that  -2 < |y-x| < 2

What's a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: You need to escape the curly braces for the set comprehension or they won't appear. Like this: \{x\in\mathbb{R}: \forall y\in \left[0,1\right],\ |y-x| < 2 \}

Answer (score 1):

The question asks – Here's a set $A$:

$$
A = \{x\in\mathbb{R}: \forall y\in \left[0,1\right],\ |y-x| < 2 \}
$$

$A$ consists of all those $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the condition
$$
\forall y\in \left[0,1\right],\ |y-x| < 2 \text{.}
$$

***Hint***

First figure out what's in $A$: which reals are in $A$, and which aren't?

- Obviously every $x \in \left[0,1\right]$ is in $A$ (why?)
- What about $x \in \left[1,2\right]$?
- $x \in \left[2,+\infty\right)$?
- $x \in \left[-1,0\right]$?
- $x \in \left(-\infty,-1\right]$?

Once you've determined what is and isn't in $A$, you'll see that $A$ can be characterized as all reals in one or more intervals. Take care to get the endpoints right.